# How do I use promises in ExcelJS

Tags: node.js, promise, exceljs

I have a node api that receives an xlsx file. It extracts records from that file and writes them to a database.

in some cases the data will not write to the database because of missing related data. I want to catch all these errors before I return the results back to the user, so I need to use a promise.

This is how [the docs show](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs#rows) the worksheet.eachRow should work

```
worksheet.eachRow(function(row, rowNumber) {
    console.log('Row ' + rowNumber + ' = ' + JSON.stringify(row.values));
});
```

the docs also say that exceljs has built in node promises [excelJS Promises](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs#0244), but the following code does not work

```
worksheet.eachRow(function(row, rowNumber) {
        console.log('Row ' + rowNumber + ' = ' + JSON.stringify(row.values));
}).then((result)=>{
  console.log("Done")
})
```

I get the error `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is true that exceljs supports promises, but that applies only to asynchronous tasks, like file I/O.

Iterating rows in a worksheet is done *synchronously*, meaning that the callback function to `eachRow` is executed immediately for each row, and only after executing those callbacks will the call to `eachRow` complete.

`eachRow` returns `undefined`, and it makes no sense to make it return a promise, since it is synchronous by nature.

Now, it becomes a different story if for each row you plan to execute an *asynchronous* task, for instance to insert something into the database.

Let's say you want to call a method `db.insert(row)` that returns a promise, then you will have one promise per row. If you collect those promises into an array, then you can do the standard `Promise.all` call to get the overall promised result:

```
const promises = [];
worksheet.eachRow(function(row, rowNumber) {
    console.log('Row ' + rowNumber + ' = ' + JSON.stringify(row.values));
    const promise = db.insert(row); // <-- whatever async operation you have here
    promises.push(promise);
});

Promise.all(promises).then((result)=>{
    console.log("Done")
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log("An error occurred while inserting data", err);
});
```

If your database API does not return promises, but uses a callback argument, then [promisify](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) the concerned method first.

Comment: Thank you. Your explanation makes sense, I just wish the exceljs documentation gave that explanation. It is quite thorough other than this, but it's this high level knowledge that it is need for anything other than the most basic usage of the library.

Comment: Glad to hear it is of use!